# Image quality problems when UILabel is rescaled and rasterized

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uilabel, scale

I have some problems in rescaling the content of a `UILabel` object when it is stored as an image. Since the rendered image has to be bigger than the original `UILabel`, I have computed the scale `imageScale` needed to rescale the original image and saved it into a `CGSize` variable. In the following, I will explain the adopted (and failing) approaches.

**Code used for rendering the image**

The following code is used for rendering the extracted image on the canvas.

```
[labelImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(xCoordinate/imageScale.width,
                                  yCoordinate/imageScale.height,
                                  newSize.width,
                                  newSize.height)
                          blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];
```

where the variable `newSize` is computed as follows:

- `newSize.width = originalWidth/imageScale.width`;
- `newSize.height = originalHeight/imageScale.height`

**Approach 1**

I extracted the label using the following code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [[label layer] renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

where `label` is the `UILabel` variable and `newSize` is the size that the rescaled image should have (see above for details).

However, I obtain the following image, which is obviously failing, since the content is very little and not centered:

[image]

**Approach 2**

I extracted the label using the following code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions([label bounds].size, NO, 0.0);
    [[label layer] renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

However, since I am using the original image size in order to extract the image, the effect I obtain is the following:

[image]

As you can notice, the text in the balloon has not a high resolution, and thus it is not visualized properly.

**The question**

How to correct one of the two approaches so as to visualize in high resolution the image?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to set appropriate scale for the generated image.

This is the function:

```
void UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
    CGSize size,
    BOOL opaque,
    CGFloat scale
);
```

You set scale as `0.0`. Try replacing it with `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not solving the problem.